# is there any method to do the countdown of time in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> This is my main.js file were am trying to add the countdown timer ,
> but it is displaying in the first card , not in all the other cards
> .please help me to get the solution .

```
    import { Grid } from "@mui/material";
    import Timer from "../MainPage/Timer";
    import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
    import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
    import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
    
    const Main = (props) => {
      const getMain = () => {
        return (
          // return console.log(props);
          <Card sx={{ m: 2, width: 400 }}>
            <CardContent>
              <Grid container spacing={2}>
                <Grid item>
                  <span className="ui top attach label">
                    {/* Match {match["Match"]} */}
                    Match {props.match.Match}
                  </span>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                  <Typography variant="h5" component="div">
                    {/* {match["Team_A"]} */}
                    {props.match.Team_A}
                  </Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                  <Typography sx={{ mb: 1.5 }} color="text.secondary">
                    {/* {match["Date"]}
                     */}
                    {props.match.Date}
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography sx={{ mb: 1.5 }} color="text.secondary">
                    {
                      <Timer
                        remainingDate={props.match.Date}
                        remainingTime={props.match.Time}
                      />
                    }
                  </Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item className="ui right aligned">
                  <Typography variant="h5" component="div">
                    {/* {match["Team_B"]} */}
                    {props.match.Team_B}
                  </Typography>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        );
      };
      // setInterval(getMain, 1000);
      return getMain();
    };
    export default Main;

Timer.js file 

const Timer = (props) => {
  // console.log(props);

  var countDownDate = new Date(
    props.remainingDate + " " + props.remainingTime
  ).getTime();

  // Update the count down every 1 second
  // var x = setInterval(function () {
  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  return days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
};

export default Timer;
```

> if am using without setInterval it displays the remaining time in all
> the Cards but when i use the setInterval it displays only on the first
> card . below is the code with the setInterval .

[without the use of setInterval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPAaQ.png)

Timer.js

```
const Timer = (props) => {
  // console.log(props);

  var countDownDate = new Date(
    props.remainingDate + " " + props.remainingTime
  ).getTime();

  // Update the count down every 1 second
  var x = setInterval(function () {
    // Get today's date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor(
      (distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)
    );
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("tmr").innerHTML =
      days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
  }, 1000);
  return (
    <div>
      <span id="tmr"></span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Timer;
```

[with the setInterval the output am getting is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV3ZT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this third-party library. It will make your life way more comfortable as it did mine.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-compound-timer

Answer (score 0):

That's probably coz you are setting the content on the same element by id.

`document.getElementById("tmr").innerHTML = ...`;

ID is same for all card items' timer and it replaces one.

Try creating dynamic IDs from props and use that.

```
const Timer = (props) => {
   const { timerId } = props;
   const timerEleId = `tmr${timerId}`;
   .
   .
   .
   document.getElementById(timerEleId).innerHTML = ...;
   .
   .
   .
   return (
    <div>
      <span id={timerEleId}></span>
    </div>);
}
```

Also, you are using react and why use declarative way of getting element by id and set it? you should use state updates on `useEffects` with setIntervals. Something similar: [Fetch data from external Api with reactjs hooks in every 10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65843705/fetch-data-from-external-api-with-reactjs-hooks-in-every-10-seconds)