# I want to refresh the api section every 10 secondes with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coingecko

I want to repeat this action and re-render it every 10 secondes. Can someone help me with that ?

```
   useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    const response = await coinGecko.get("/coins/markets", {
      params: {
        vs_currency: "usd",
        ids: watchList.join(","),
      }
    })
    setCoins(response.data)
    setIsLoading(false)
  }

  fetchData()
},[])
```

Comment: Welcome! Same question (with solution) here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65843705/fetch-data-from-external-api-with-reactjs-hooks-in-every-10-seconds

Comment: Use `setInterval` in your hook - many resources on how to do that. You could even make a custom [useInterval](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/snippets/react-hooks/use-interval/) hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define a state: `const [repeater,setRepeater]=useState(0)`
in your useEffect pass it as second argument so whenever it is changed, your useEffect would run again. Now let's take care of the 10 second intervals with this piece of code:
    `setTimeout(() => setRepeater(prevState=>prevState+1), 100000);`
and finally implement it like tis:

```
   useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    const response = await coinGecko.get("/coins/markets", {
      params: {
        vs_currency: "usd",
        ids: watchList.join(","),
      }
    })
    setCoins(response.data)
    setIsLoading(false)
  }

  fetchData()
  setTimeout(() => setRepeater(prevState=>prevState+1), 100000);
},[repeater])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it help me to understand how it work. Thank you.

Comment: `setInterval` inside `useEffect` seems to be the right approach.

Comment: How do you clear the repeater so it won't trigger when you navigate to the next screen?